# What are the maximal ideals of $C_0 (X),$ where $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: compactness, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, maximal-and-prime-ideals, banach-algebras

> How do the maximal ideals of $C_0(X)$ look like where $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space?

I know that if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space then the maximal ideals of $C(X)$ are of the form $I_{c} : = \left \{f \in C(X)\ |\ f(c) = 0 \right \},$ for some $c \in X.$ I can also able to show that if $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space then $I_{c}$ is a maximal ideal of $C_0 (X)$ but can't able to prove the converse of that. Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks a bunch.

**EDIT** $:$ Let $X^+$ denote the one point compactification of $X.$ Let $\varphi : C_0(X) \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ be a multiplicative linear functional on $C_0(X).$ Then it can be extended to a multiplicative linear functional $\overline {\varphi} : C(X^+) \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ defined by $\overline {\varphi} (f) = \varphi \left (f\ \big |_{X} \right ).$ Also given any $f \in C_0(X)$ there is an unique way to extend it to a function $\overline {f} \in C(X^+)$ as follows $:$ $$\overline {f} (x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & x \in X \\ 0 & x = \infty \end{cases}$$ Now take any $f \in C_0(X).$  Then since $X^+$ is compact we have $\varphi (f) = \overline {\varphi} (\overline {f}) = \overline {f} (c),$ for some $c \in X^+.$ If $c = \infty$ we have $\varphi \equiv 0$ i.e. $\varphi$ is a zero linear functional on $C_0(X).$ Otherwise there always exixts some $c \in X$ such that $\varphi (f) = f(c),$ for all $f \in C_0(X).$ So for any non-zero multiplicative linear functional $\varphi$ on $C_0(X)$ we have $\text {Ker}\ (\varphi) = \{f \in C_0(X)\ |\ f(c) = 0 \} = I_{c},$ for some $c \in X.$ Since we know that maximal ideals in any Banach algebra $A$ are precisely the kernels of non-zero multiplicative linear functionals on $A$ and $C_0(X)$ is a Banach algebra (in fact a $C^{\ast}$-algebra) we are through.

**Possible Mistake** $:$ I think where my above argument goes wrong is the stage where I assume $f\ \big |_{X} \in C_0 (X)$ whenever $f \in C(X^{+}).$ Instead when $f \in C_0 (X^+)$ this happens. Now we need to search for maximal ideals of $\{f \in C(X^+)\ |\ f(\infty) = 0 \}.$ So the above is not a valid argument. What my above argument shows is the following $:$

> Multiplicative linear functionals on $C(X)$ are precisely evaluations even if $X$ is locally compact.

So the original question ultimately boils down to the following question  $:$

> Can we always extend every multiplicative linear functional on $C_0(X)$ to a multiplicative linear functional on $C(X)$ if $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space?

Comment: Phrasing nitpick: "I can also able to show that if $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space then $I_{c}$ is a maximal ideal of $C_0 (X)$ but can't able to prove the converse of that." sounds like you want to prove that if $I_c$ is a maximal ideal, then $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff.

Comment: @Arthur$:$ Sorry I am not a English speaking person. If some of my phrasing in the above question is inappropriate pardon me please. What I tried to mean by the **converse** is the following $:$ If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space then can we say that all the maximal ideals of $C_0(X)$ are of the form $I_{c}\ $? Hope there's no further ambiguity in my argument above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to use that we identify $C_0(X)$ with the linear subspace $L = \{ f \in C(X^+) \mid f(\infty) = 0\}$ of $C(X^+)$, where $X^+$ denotes the one-point compactifacation of $X$.

Comment: @Paul Frost$:$ Could you please elaborate a little more e.g. how does it help? Thanks.

Comment: @RabinKumarChakraborty It was just an idea to get a relation to the compact case. I do not know whether it is really useful.

Comment: @Paul Frost$:$ Is it possible to transfer this post to MO?

Comment: @RabinKumarChakraborty You can of course crosspost it in MO, but I doubt that this an adequate place. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathOverflow: *It is primarily for asking questions on mathematics research – i.e. related to unsolved problems and the extension of knowledge of mathematics into areas that are not yet known.*

Comment: @Paul Frost $:$ I think I got the idea. I am trying to share it. I can able to show that any multiplicative linear functional on $C_0(X)$ is an evaluation.

Comment: @Paul Frost $:$ Please have a look at my edited question where I tried to add my thoughts.